# What is this closed bag with a valve for?

Tags: backpacks

[image: REI pouch with carrying handles]

Does anybody know what this is? Somebody gave me this with their old pack.

Comment: It is almost certainly a bag designed to carry something liquid or perhaps (but unlikely) act as a dry-bag. The thing on the lower right is a valve for pouring - like on a box-wine. Can you supply some photos of the opening and other side?

Comment: could it be a shower?

Comment: Does the top of the bag seal in any way?

Comment: Can you post a little more info about it? It looks like it might be able to seal and hold water, can it? Maybe a shot inside as well.

Comment: How do I add more photos? It seems this site will only let me add one at a time.

Comment: @Stanley new users are limited to how many photos they can add to a post, but if you upload them to Imgur  and leave a note here, one of us can add them

Comment: Is it waterproof enough to use as a folding bucket?

Comment: @Stanley Have you tried emailing REI customer services and asking them?

Answer (score 7):

I expect it's a camp tap. You fill it with water, hang it somewhere by the handle, and can get a little water from the wine-box like valve on it. It doesn't take up space when it's empty, unlike a bottle, and you don't need two hands to operate it, are less likely to overpour or spill, etc.

Here's one of the water storage bags REI sells these days:

[image: rei water storage bag]

Comment: I'm sure you nailed it.  The bag is obviously meant to be filled by scooping from a water source--fine if you have clean, deep enough water available but it would be nearly useless with shallow water that could still be recovered fine with a pump.

Answer (score -1):

After you pack clothing into it , it can be evacuated through the valve to compress the clothing to the smallest volume.

Comment: Huh?  The top looks open and it's REI--why in the world would they be selling a vacuum-based compression bag anyway?  There's rarely a source of suction where REI products are being used.  Furthermore, if it is a vacuum compression bag why the handles?  That's wasted weight, anathema in the backcountry.  (Now, they might sell a roll-up compression bag but it wouldn't look like that.)